# dotnet publish fails with 'Metadata generation failed' sometimes

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions

We have an Azure function app. Runtime version is 2. Occasionally this command fails on our build server (Jenkins running on Windows Server):

```
dotnet publish C:\temp\OurFunctionApp.csproj -c Release -o C:\temp\output
```

The error:

> C:\Users\user1.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator\1.0.1\build\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.targets(20,5): error : Metadata generation failed. [C:\temp\OurFunctionApp.csproj]

When I run this command from command line it always works fine.

We don't have Visual Studio installed on our build server.

How to diagnose and fix this error?

.csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.8.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project1\Project1.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project2\Project2.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project3\Project3.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project4\Project4.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="ourlist.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: This only happens occasionally? Can you share your function csproj file?

Comment: @brettsam Yes, occasionally only. I added content of .csproj file to my question.

Comment: Weird - mid-day yesterday the exact same thing started happening on our build server. It's also intermittent. I would guess maybe 1 in 5 builds, the Azure Function apps all error with this same message `Metadata generation failed`.

Comment: Upgraded to latest VS2017 on build machine, seems okay for now.

Comment: Ah, we don't have Visual Studio installed on our build server.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker Pavel also raised https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4055 for this - please add to that thread if you would like

Comment: For anyone following this -- could you try again with our latest SDK package? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions/1.0.26. Do you get the same thing?

Comment: Still happening for us too:
<code>
C:\Users\buildcode\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.script.extensionsmetadatagenerator\1.1.2\build\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.targets(33,5): error : Metadata generation failed. Exit code: '255' Error: '' [D:\Jenkins\workspaces\rvices_sapphire-formdata_develop\develop\src\FormDataService.Functions\FormDataService.Functions.csproj]
</code>

We delete the full source folder, I think mainly this deletes the ./bin and ./obj folders, and then it *usually* works again for awhile

Comment: @brettsam this is still happening with version 1.0.29, a few times per week

Comment: Do any answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with Net Framework 4.7.

To solve the problem you should update `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` nuget package.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid the same issue, i have created a Windows accounts (Admin) by DevOps Agent.

The goal of that is to have for each account it's own folder for nugets. (No more // issues on the same folder)
C:\Users\Agent1.nuget
C:\Users\Agent2.nuget
...

Since i have change all Windows service with the new windows account i have no more errors in my builds ;) (need to restart the Agent Windows Service)

Answer (score 1):

After sometime I just deleted and recreate the application. That worked to me

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I updated Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions to version 3+ while I still had a version 2 function. I installed and target v1.0.37 and that resolved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to the csproj file:

```
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

is what fixed it for me.